# What difference between Daily Build and Alpha 2 (12.10)?

Tags: installation, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference & Stability of alpha/beta and daily-live](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115565/stability-of-alpha-beta-and-daily-live)

I have went into 12.10 ubuntu website but have 2 vision,one is  Daily Build another one is   Alpha 2.

What difference between Daily Build and  Alpha 2 (12.10)?

Which one I should download?